# Keeping my Sub Menu open when hovering on its list items

Tags: menus, css, dropdown

I'm building a custom theme from scratch and I'm stuck on this dropdown styling. I am able to have the sub-menu appear when its containing `<li>` is hovered but when I go to transition my mouse off the parent `<li>` and onto the sub menu and it's items, it disappears. Would love a quick solution on how to keep the sub-menu open when I'm hovering it and its children. Here are the styles I have so far (in LESS form).

```
.primary-nav .nav-links ul li .sub-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  display: none;
  min-width: 150px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  li{
    float: none;
  }
}
.primary-nav .nav-links #menu-primary > li > a{
  height: 90px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}
.primary-nav .nav-links #menu-primary > li {
  &:hover{
    ul{
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class called `has-children` to all inner li's. You can use `wp_nav_menu_objects` to add the `has-children` class.